# The area of the region bounded by two functions $y=x^2$ & $y=2-x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, volume

I am solving a question on double integrals, and I drew the graph and all but I am not sure if the limits of $x$ (since I am doing $dydx$) if it is $0 \ to \ 1$ or $-1 \ to \ 1.$ Which is correct and why? Can you also switch the integration to $dxdy$?

> The area of the region bounded between $y = x^2$ and $y = 2 − x^2$ is given by : ?

Comment: Do you have to write it as a double integral? Seems like $\int_{-1}^{1}[(2-x^2)-(x^2)]dx$ is pretty straightforward-integrating upper function minus lower function for the area between their intersections.

Comment: Yes this is the question, it's over a general region f(x,y) I just need to put the limits of x and y properly.

Comment: You can write the integrand above as another integral. $1 dy$ with lower limit $x^2$ and upper limit $2-x^2$.

Comment: Yes but what about the limits of x, and can you reverse the order of integration to dx and dy?